# Do you need FAA approval to land a helicopter on Miami Beach?

Tags: faa-regulations, helicopter

Do you need FAA approval to land a helicopter on Miami Beach, Florida?

Comment: To narrow this down, do you mean the actual beach front, within the city of Miami Beach? or do you mean anywhere in the city?

Answer (score 5):

No; you may need permission from the local authority.  FAA doesn't regulate where you can land or take off.

Comment: Unless that place happens to be a controlled field!

Answer (score 3):

If you are in an emergency then get on the ground and deal with the fallout after everyone is safe and sound.

Besides that it's the land owner's call about whether you can land on his property, otherwise you will be trespassing with all due consequences.